What extra material do you need to run Kingmaker campagin in pathfinder 1e with the last edition of the adventure path?
Some years ago Paizo crowdfunded a new revisited version to this famous adventure path, updating it to the new 2ed rules for Pathfinder. They also published a monster manual for 1ed which includes stats for NPCs so you can play the adventure path using the new edition with old rules.
It's enough to use this monster manual or are there further materials or publishings you'd need to smootlhy run the campaign with older rules?

I assume you are talking about the Pathfinder Kingmaker Bestiary (PFRPG):
https://paizo.com/products/btq02e0f?Pathfinder-Kingmaker-Bestiary
Note there are two versions of Kingmaker. The original 1E version, and the 2E version. If your intention is to just play a 1E kingmaker game, I'd recomend just buying the 1E adventure path. If, however, you want to run the new adventure path with its updated adventures, monsters, etc., but back-ported into 1E, this will take some work.
For one thing, you will require the New PF2E Kingmaker adventure path as well as this book.
From Pazio's site:

This book presents rules for over 200 monsters and villains, 45 traps
and hazards, and seven companion NPCs presented with a low-level and
mid-level stat block, making them suitable for play as adventuring
companions or even pregenerated player characters—all compatible with
any Pathfinder First Edition game. Designed to work alongside the new
Kingmaker Adventure Path campaign book, this volume makes quick
conversion of the campaign to Pathfinder First Edition a breeze!

This means it is intended to be used to help you convert. However, it mentions stat blocks for companions and monsters, as well as stats for traps and hazards. It does not, however, make any mention of converting anything else, such as skill checks, treasure allocations, etc. Expect to have to do this yourself. Here is an example I found of a skill check table to convert between the editions: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17lA-ymHQKg38AHzyQQT8X7BoOoYlfc5FKucpwGUh0N8/edit?gid=0#gid=0
The TLDR is you will need this book, the 2E adventure path, and to find or come up with your own way to backdate skill checks, treasure allotments, and any other miscellaneous rules this book does not include to make this work.

alongside that, encounter balancing is vastly different, so you'll probably have to retool a lot of encounters for First Edition more than just using the different stat blocks.
